# How can I solve Cannot read property 'name' of undefined problem?

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm trying to build a signup form using the react-hook form. I'm trying to build a restaurant website for my own purpose. But I have tried many times. But I'm getting many errors. It will be great if someone helps me. There are many errors that I need to solve.

can someone help, please?

**Here is the signup.js file**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from './useAuth'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import logo from '../../Images/logo2.png';
import './SignUp.css'

const SIgnUp = () => {

    const [returningUser, setReturningUser] = useState(false);
    const {register, handleSubmit, watch, errors} = useForm();
    
    const auth = useAuth();

    const onSubmit = data => {
        if(returningUser){
            if(data.email && data.password){
            auth.signIn(data.email, data.password)
            }
        }
        else{
            if(data.name, data.email, data.password){
                auth.signUp(data.name, data.email, data.password)
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="sign-up">
            <div className="container">

            <div className="logo-container ">
                <img src={logo} alt=""/>

            </div>
            {
                returningUser ?
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} action="" className="py-5">
                    
                    {
                        auth.user != null && <p className="text-danger">{auth.user.error}</p>
                    }
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" className="form-control" {...register( {requried: true})} placeholder="Email"/>
                        {errors.email && <span className="error">Email is Required</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" {...register({requried: true})} placeholder="password"/>
                        {errors.password && <span className="error">Password is Required</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-danger">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="option text-center">
                        <label  onClick={() => setReturningUser(false)}>Create a new Account</label>
                    </div>



                </form>
                :
                <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control" 
                       
                       {...register({requried: true})} placeholder="Name"/>
                        {errors.name && <span className="error">Name is Required</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" {...register({requried: true})} placeholder="Confirm password"/>
                        {errors.password && <span className="error">Password is Required</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <button className="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>


                    </div>
                    <div className="option text-center">
                        <label onClick={() => setReturningUser(true)}>Already have an account!</label>
                    </div>


                </form>
            }

            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SIgnUp;
```

Here are the errors:

```
SIgnUp
T:/1.Full-Stack-Developer/5.React/3.Red Onion/red-onion-resturant/src/components/SignUp/SIgnUp.js:65
  62 | :
  63 | <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  64 |     <div className="form-group">
> 65 |         <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control" 
     | ^  66 |        
  67 |        {...register('name', {requried: true})} placeholder="Name"/>
  68 |         {errors.name && <span className="error">Name is Required</span>}
```

Comment: Welcome! What are the errors?

Comment: <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  64 |     <div className="form-group">
> 65 |         <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control" 
     | ^  66 |        
  67 |        {...register('name', {requried: true})} placeholder="Name"/>
  68 |         {errors.name && <span className="error">Name is Required</span>}

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: I would strongly recommend adding these errors into the post, not as a comment

Comment: I did it.you can check it now

Comment: You get error because __data__ in `onSubmit` is undefined. Why do you need `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}`. Is not `onSubmit={onSubmit}` good enough?

Comment: why it is undefined. how can I check returning users or not!

Comment: I'm still getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because your error object is not defined, bevcause you arent having any errors yet.

add to this line:

```
{errors.name && <span className="error">Name is Required</span>}
```

a verification for error:

```
{ errors && errors.name && <span className="error">Name is Required</span>}
```

You have to do this kind of verification each time you have the error: `Cannot read property [variable] of undefined problem?`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: ur welcome! a good practice is make all this verification in another hook or better isolated